# How can I change the background colour of my Action Bar (Material Design)?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, material-design

I would like my Action Bar to have a background with value @color/colorPrimary (last item) but in my app, the action bar takes the same colour as my background.  It looks like they are both 1 element. How can I style my Action Bar (font, background, ...)? I won't have to style it dynamically, it will maintain the same colour throughout the activities.

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/background</item> **BACKGROUND**
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@color/colorPrimary</item> **ACTION BAR**
    </style>
</resources>
```

color.xml

```
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#E91E63</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#880E4F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#E91E63</color>
    <color name="background">#FCE4EC</color>
</resources>
```

My Action Bar does NOT apply the color I want.

Comment: ActionBar get the colorPrimary as its color

Comment: Go to `color.xml` and change the `colorPrimary` or change in the `style.xml`

Comment: I have done both of your suggestions, it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet of code

```
   <resources>
        <!-- Base application theme. -->
        <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
 <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_primary</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_primary_dark</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent_color</item>
        </style>
    </resources>
```

From Java:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
            new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1e8d93")));
```

Comment: Well I actually want to apply the Material theme, not the AppCompat one

Comment: @Helenesh, try this-  getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1e8d93")));

Comment: Yes, even with your piece of code, the background colour of my action bar does not change (I want to colour colorPrimary). If you want, feel free to check out my code on Github https://github.com/heleneshaikh/popular_movies_udacitiy.git

Comment: try to set Actionbar from code and set BG...check code

Comment: I found the solution:  <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item> I wonder why people gave me negative points because it's a very useful question for later references! I found the solution after a lot of research on material design ;-) Thanks for your help Sreekanth!

Answer (score 0):

Using `android:background` in your app theme is not a good idea, as this will apply the background color to *all* views, including the action bar. Instead use `android:windowBackground` to set the window background color of the activities.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it's color like this:

```
ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();

if(ab != null) {   
    ab.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.RED));
}
```